# Type hints for the generic utility in the Django

Tags: python, django, type-hinting

```
def get_or_create_object(self, model : ?(what will be the type?), data: dict) -> ? (what will be the return type):
        try:
            obj, _ = model.objects.get_or_create(**data)
        except model.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            obj = model.objects.filter(**data).first()
        return obj

get_or_create_object(ModelName, data)
```

What will be the type hint here - as function will get the Model instances dynamically.

Comment: TypeVar is the best choice: you return the object of specified type. `_T = TypeVar('_T', bound=models.Model)`, `get_or_create_object(model: type[T], data: dict[str, Any]) -> _T`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `models.Model` or `Type[models.Model]` All Django models inherit from `models.Model` and the model that is sent to the function is of the same type, of course, if you want to say that it is a class and is a subset of this class, you can use Type[models.Model]

```
from typing import Type
from django.db import models

def get_or_create_object(model: Type[models.Model], data: dict) -> models.Model:
    try:
        obj, _ = model.objects.get_or_create(**data)
    except model.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        obj = model.objects.filter(**data).first()
    return obj
```

note:
`get_or_create` is exist in Django build-in:

```
exp = Example.objects.get_or_create(**data)
```

Comment: "`get_or_create` exists in Django" this addition looks weird 5 lines below of OP's example using it in implementation.

Comment: @SUTerliakov The question of the questioner is about typing in Python, but I guessed that maybe there is a problem in using Django that wants to create this function, I wanted to give an additional guide.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? This not generic in any way. The output is just of type `Model` and not of a specific subtype. Also the `model` annotation is wrong because it should accept a class not an instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want your function to be generic in terms of the specific model class you pass to it, the solution is what @SUTerliakov said in his comment. You need to define a [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) and ideally give it an upper bound of `Model` to narrow the types it can represent. See the relevant [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics) section for details.

Here is how you do it:

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar, cast

from django.db.models import Model


M = TypeVar("M", bound=Model)


def get_or_create_object(model: type[M], data: dict[str, Any]) -> M:
    try:
        obj, _ = model.objects.get_or_create(**data)
    except model.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        obj = cast(M, model.objects.filter(**data).first())
    return obj
```

Note that we need to use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) because the [`QuerySet.first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#first) method can return an instance of the model **or `None`** and type checkers are not smart enough to know that in this specific situation it can never return `None` (due to the previously caught `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception). So we need to make it clear to the type checker that the value is indeed an instance of our model.

To demonstrate:

```py
class SpecificModel(Model):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 1


instance = get_or_create_object(SpecificModel, {})
reveal_type(instance)
reveal_type(instance.foo())
```

Running `mypy` over this gives the following output:

```
note: Revealed type is "SpecificModel"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

Thus the type checker correctly infers the type of the instance returned by the function.

---

As a side note, if you wanted you could actually broaden the type of `data` because it can be literally any [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), not necessarily a dictionary. For that you just do `from collections.abc import Mapping` and annotate it with `data: Mapping[str, Any]` instead.

Comment: M = TypeVar("M", bound=Model), this also indicates that the type is bound to models.Model, then what will be the exact difference here?  @Daniil

Comment: @Iceman You should definitely read a bit about what generics are. I provided all the links. But in short: The difference to just using `Model` is that the output type will be inferred from whatever class is passed to the `model` argument. In my example the output type is inferred as `SpecificModel`, which is narrower than just `Model`. If we just annotat the output type with `Model` it would _always_ be seen as just that. The upper bound of the type variable signals that you must not pass any class that _does not_ inherit from `Model`.